# PHP skipping script and click anchor tag

Tags: php

I have a form. After the form is filled out and the user clicks the submit button the user is taken to a thank you page. On the thank you page is a link (anchor tag) for the user to get to her home page. It works fine 19 out of 20 times.

The problem is, sometimes php skips the thank you page and goes directly to the home page. How is this possible? How is php clicking the link? I've gone over the code and it's completely correct. There is no javascript, just html and css.

Like I said, it doesn't do it every time and I guess it's not a bid deal I'd just like to understand what's going on. I'm using a simple header redirect like so

```
$url = "thanks/";
header("Location: $url");
exit();
```

What do you guys think is going? Is there any way to stop it?

Thanks

Comment: Code looks fine... Probably the problem is in other part of the code...

Comment: Sounds like redirecting to a default page when the requested page is not found. Can you reproduce this behavior somehow? And have you tried tracking the requests made by the browser (like e.g. with the 'Live HTTP Headers'-AddOn for FireFox) and then compared both cases?

Comment: the problem could be your $url variable ... if you actual site is for example http://mysite/form.php then it will foward you to http://mysite/thanks/ and if your site is http://mysite/form then it will forward you to http://mysite/form/thanks ... i dont know which framework you use but i think this could be a problem with your header forward.

Comment: I can't recreate it because it only happens once in awhile and I don;t know why. I use custom error pages so if the page isn't found you'll get a 404 error. I'm not using any framework. Do you think I should use an absolute URL? Will that work better?

Comment: an absolute url is probably the safest way to go in this scenario anyways, so why not?

Comment: Live HTTP Headers is a cool tool but if you have ads on your site it can be hard to follow. Thanks for the tip though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [RFC for the Location header](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.30) requires a single absolute URI. This is also pointed out in the [PHP manual](http://uk.php.net/manual/en/function.header.php) in the notes section:

> HTTP/1.1 requires an absolute URI as argument to » Location: including
>   the scheme, hostname and absolute path, but some clients accept
>   relative URIs. You can usually use $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'],
>   $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] and dirname() to make an absolute URI from a
>   relative one yourself

The problem may be to do with the fact that you're passing non standard headers to the browser. Browsers interpret the malformed header string differently and don't always behave as expected. Again as demonstrated in the PHP manual you should create an absolute URI, not an absolute or relative path before passing it to the `header()` function.

```
/* Redirect to a different page in the current directory that was requested */
$host  = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
$uri   = rtrim(dirname($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']), '/\\');
$extra = 'mypage.php';
header("Location: http://$host$uri/$extra");
exit;
```

Comment: I read that in the PHP manual but didn't think it applied. Plus I'm redirecting to a different directory. None of this explains how it gets to a page that can't be reached without clicking a link. I'll admit I've not done a lot with headers but it was working 99% of the time. Thanks for a new idea though.

Comment: I'm not finished checking but using the absolute path seems to be doing the trick. I still don't understand how the browser was following the <A href> tag on the thanks page without displaying the page or doing any of the processing. Strange.

Comment: It's almost certainly not following the `<a>` tag- you said the anchor href attribute points to the homepage. It's more likely that the `Location` header is malformed and the browser picks up the domain from elsewhere in the headers making it look like it's following the link but in effect it's just going to www.domain.com